# Chart.js - how to have statis lables and populate with dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on chart.js and I have data coming from JSON via ajax. See the example below:

[{"timestamp":"06:00:00.000000","true_count":2},{"timestamp":"07:00:00.000000","true_count":5},{"timestamp":"08:00:00.000000","true_count":7},{"timestamp":"09:00:00.000000","true_count":8},{"timestamp":"10:00:00.000000","true_count":12},{"timestamp":"11:00:00.000000","true_count":15},{"timestamp":"12:00:00.000000","true_count":20},{"timestamp":"13:00:00.000000","true_count":17},{"timestamp":"14:00:00.000000","true_count":14},{"timestamp":"16:00:00.000000","true_count":11},{"timestamp":"17:00:00.000000","true_count":19},{"timestamp":"18:00:00.000000","true_count":22},{"timestamp":"19:00:00.000000","true_count":16},{"timestamp":"20:00:00.000000","true_count":14},{"timestamp":"22:00:00.000000","true_count":7}]

The JS code i am using for my chart is below:

```
    // create initial empty chart
var ctx_live = document.getElementById("chLine");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx_live, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor:'#00c0ef',
      label: 'liveCount',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Count Per Hour",
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});


// logic to get new data
var getData = function() {
   var _data =[];
   var _labels = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: 'chart_data',
         type: "get",
    success: function(data) {
    full_data = JSON.parse(data);
    full_data.forEach(function(key,index) {
    _data.push(key.true_count);
    _labels.push(key.hour);
 });
    
    myChart.data.labels = _labels;
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = _data;

      myChart.update();
    }
  });
};

// get new data every 3 seconds
setInterval(getData, 3000);
```

Now, this is working fine and shows the true_count over time which is a one-hour basis. Now, the chart is showing only hours with count but what I would like to do is to set the static hours from 12 AM to 11 PM, and for hours for which I don't have data the true_count will be zero, and for those that I have data for, the true count will be assigned to that hour and show on the chart.

Any ideas on how do I do that?

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsfiddle (or similar) from this code, so we can check how it is working?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. :-(

Comment: I think I am starting to understand what you need to do. Can you add to the question the real JSON you get, not this "empty" one?

Comment: @Anton -  Hi, i added the json file. As yo can see for this particual day i dont have true_counts between 12am and 6am, there is no true_count for 3PM,9PM and 11PM. However I need to create statics Axist to show 12am to 11pm and for the hours that i have no data for it should be zero.

Comment: Do you always have format `22:00:00.000000`? Or it can be for example '22:01:02.300000` sometimes? (I mean minutes and seconds always zero?)

Comment: I am rounding that time before I produce the JSON, so in json it will always be 22:00:00.000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
// create initial empty chart
var ctx_live = document.getElementById("chLine");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx_live, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#00c0ef',
      label: 'liveCount',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Count Per Hour",
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

// Some constants to be changed later:
const HOUR_TO_START = 0;
const HOUR_TO_END = 23;
// helper:
const intToAmPm = (i) => 
  i==0 ? '12 AM' :
  i==12 ? '12 PM' :
  i < 12 ? i + ' AM' :
  (i-12) + ' PM';

// logic to get new data
var getData = function() {
  var _data = [];
  var _labels = [];
  $ajax({
    url: 'chart_data',
    type: "get",
    success: function(data) {
      full_data = JSON.parse(data);
      let preparedData = {};
      full_data.forEach(function(key, index) {
        let hour = parseInt(String(key.timestamp).substring(0, 2));
        preparedData[hour] = key.true_count;
      });
      for (let i = HOUR_TO_START; i <= HOUR_TO_END; i++) {
        _data.push(preparedData[i] === undefined ? 0 : preparedData[i]);
        _labels.push(intToAmPm(i));
      }

      myChart.data.labels = _labels;
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = _data;

      myChart.update();
    }
  });
};

// get new data every 3 seconds
//setInterval(getData, 3000);
getData();

// THIS IS FOR TESTING. IMITATE BACKEND
function $ajax(param) {
  param.success('[{"timestamp":"06:00:00.000000","true_count":2},{"timestamp":"07:00:00.000000","true_count":5},{"timestamp":"08:00:00.000000","true_count":7},{"timestamp":"09:00:00.000000","true_count":8},{"timestamp":"10:00:00.000000","true_count":12},{"timestamp":"11:00:00.000000","true_count":15},{"timestamp":"12:00:00.000000","true_count":20},{"timestamp":"13:00:00.000000","true_count":17},{"timestamp":"14:00:00.000000","true_count":14},{"timestamp":"16:00:00.000000","true_count":11},{"timestamp":"17:00:00.000000","true_count":19},{"timestamp":"18:00:00.000000","true_count":22},{"timestamp":"19:00:00.000000","true_count":16},{"timestamp":"20:00:00.000000","true_count":14},{"timestamp":"22:00:00.000000","true_count":7}]');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chLine"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It worked exactly how i need it.  If you ever come to Atlanta, you have lunch om me. :-)

Comment: one more question, would it be possible to have it as AM and PM instead of 0-23?

Comment: @Slavisha84 just one question because I use 24-hour: is 12:00 (middle of a day) - it is 12AM or 12PM or just simple 12?

Comment: So in that example 00:00:00 would be 12AM and 12:00:00 would be 12PM

Comment: @Slavisha84 as you say, ok. I've updated my answer.